# SAG webMethods WmTestSuite UnknownServiceException wm.ps.serviceMock:loadMock

Tags: unit-testing, classpath, webmethods

I'm using the SAG webMethods Test Suite in Designer 10.3 to write unit tests.  It works fine until I set up a mock for a service.  The test run then terminates with:

```
com.wm.app.b2b.server.UnknownServiceException: wm.ps.serviceMock:loadMock
    at com.wm.app.b2b.server.comm.DefaultServerRequestHandler.handleMessage(DefaultServerRequestHandler.java:59)
    at com.wm.app.b2b.server.HTTPMessageHandler.process(HTTPMessageHandler.java:163)
    at com.wm.app.b2b.server.HTTPDispatch.handleRequest(HTTPDispatch.java:190)
    at com.wm.app.b2b.server.Dispatch.run(Dispatch.java:401)
    at com.wm.util.pool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It looks like I'm missing a package or JAR - but which one?

Answer (score 1):

The missing package is WmServiceMock.